# JavaScript Dynamically remove numbered array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which looks like below

```
{
  "containers": [
    {
    "fields": [
        {},
        {},
        'associative1': {},
        'associative2': {}
      ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically "fields" is an array which has elements like both fields[0], fields[1] & fields[associative1], fields[associative2]

My question is can I dynamically remove "just" the numbered elements...
so finally 'fields' should just have associative1, associative2 elements

Comment: That array is not valid, you can't have named elements in an array literal.

Comment: Where and how you get this object, seems like it is not actually data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating a valid object that looks like what it seems you intend...**

```
var a = [{abc:1},{xyz:2}];
a.associative1 = {};
a.associative2 = {};
console.log(a);
```

Output (from Chrome)

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, associative1: {…}, associative2: {…}]
0: {abc: 1}
1: {xyz: 2}
associative1: {}
associative2: {}
length: 2
```

**You can remove just the numbered array elements like this...**

```
a.splice(0,a.length);
```

Or if the Array object is contained in a larger object something like this will work...

```
c.containers[0].fields.splice(0,c.containers[0].fields.length)
```

Comment: Looks awesome...Just a quick question....What exactly is the type of "a" here & how does JavaScript allow assigning a.associative1 if It is declared as an array ...like it seems to be mixing types

Comment: @testndtv Javascript reports typeof a === 'object'.  Arrays in Javascript have type 'object'. But, not every object in Javascript is an array. Array.isArray(a) === true. But Array.isArray({0:"hi"})===false. So you may want to check whether an object is an array before attempting to use Array methods like splice, that do not exist for non-Array objects.

Comment: @testndtv Recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array The Description section speaks briefly about Javascript objects' associative array properties vs. Array elements.

Comment: Thx...Yes, I do see on the page why/how that syntax is allowed...But still wondering what  "object property collection" of an array means  (as referred on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Properties)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var data = {
  "containers": [
    {
    "fields": [
        {'abc': 1},
        {'xyz': 2},
        {'associative1': {}},
        {'associative2': {}}
    ]   
    }
  ]
};


for(var k in data["containers"][0]["fields"]){
 for(var key in data["containers"][0]["fields"][k]){
  if(!isNaN(data["containers"][0]["fields"][k][key])){
    delete data["containers"][0]["fields"][k];
  }
 }
}

data["containers"][0]["fields"] = data["containers"][0]["fields"].filter(function( element ) {
   return element !== undefined;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your JSON is invalid. I've changed the JSON a little bit.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @testndtv If you are satisfied please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an invalid object. The fields array include name properties, which is not allowed. Fields must be an object in that case. If test setting a variable to that object (just in a browser console) it will fail.

Comment: So I can reference fields[0], fields[1], fields[associative1], etc